# On clearing the data in search view, it should erase the filtered list and populate the original list

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

HomeFragment.kt

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return setupBindings(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            //filter the data in step 2
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String): Boolean {
            orderHistoryViewModel.search(query)
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

I have written setOnQueryTextListener in the Fragment. When I run the app, it is working only once. But how do I erase the filtered list and populate the original list everytime i clear the data from search bar and filter again when the new data is typed.

I wrote the search function in viewmodel. The below code filters data from the orinal list and populates the filtered list.

ViewModel.kt

```
fun search(query: String) {

    var filteredList =
        orderHistoryDetails?.orderList?.value?.filter { x -> x.order.contains(query) }

    orderHistoryDetails?.orderList?.value = filteredList

}
```

Comment: Don't overwrite your **original list**. Check `query` if it's `empty` then return **original list** otherwise **filtered list**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store original list also,and check whether query string is empty or not.

```
 fun search(text: String) {
        val filterList: MutableList<OrderItem> = arrayListOf()
        if (text.trim().length == 0) {
            filterList.clear()
            filterList.addAll(listOriginal)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            listOriginal.filter {x->
              x.order.toUpperCase.contains(text)
            }.apply {
                filterList.clear()
                filterList.addAll(this)
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that and search is working only once. When I clear the data and enter new data, filtering is not happening again.

Comment: May be your original list is overwritten by filtered list, I have updated my answer the way I used and worked for me and may be there is some variable corrections required in my ans, please check if it helps.

Comment: I have fixed the error. It is working fine now. Thank you so much

Comment: Great. If it helps you please consider it accept and upvote so it helps other also.

Comment: When there are no results I have to show "no details found" and this card view should go. How can I do that?

Comment: After if else condition you can check size of filter list or if there is adapter you can check adapter?.itemCount == 0